# Tablet Hover Substitution

Tags: javascript, css, hover, tablet

I'm aware that this is an 'old question' by now, but I have searched and not yet found an explanation that makes sense to me.

Note: I know just enough html, css, and wordpress to have developed my website: (http://www.gregorygainsborough.com), and am just beginning to learn javascript.

If you visit my site, you'll see the problem - much of the content is revealed when various boxes are hovered on. On tablet, since there is no :hover, I'd like to make it do this:
First tap -> reveal the style that would have been applied on :hover.
Second tap -> follow the link like a mouse click would.

ALSO helpful would be to 'close' the :hover style when a) another element is tapped, or b) ten seconds elapse.

Thanks for any help you can offer. I'm aware that some of this will be above my js knowledge at present, and I'm looking for explanations or references which can help me target my learning and close that gap.

Comment: Use PHP to detect if Tablet is used, if used, then with Javascript control when it is clicked, check if it is first time it is clicked. That would do the trick ;)

Comment: sounds great! two questions: a) can you offer references to what that code would actually be, and b) would that still leave the current :hover->style and click->link functionality intact on the lap/desktop?

Comment: I'm making a answer now.

Comment: In my opinion, using hover to hide information on any device is bad UI. Don't use it. Problem solved.

Comment: Mark - thanks!
bookcasey - yeah probably. especially in the next few years as tablet use continues to climb. but in the meantime, I still love my hovers, and the suggested functionality will both do the job and help me learn js!

Answer (score 0):

I would in PHP make a `IF` statement to check if Tablet is used.
You can use [**this Library**](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) for this. Then I would in the `IF` statement echo this javascript out:

```
var clicked = 0;
$('a.iftablet').on('click',function(){
    var old_clicked = clicked;
    var number = $(this).attr('tablet_id'); // Get the tablet ID for this item
    var clicked = number;
    if (old_clicked != number){ return false;} // This might do the trick, so that on first click, it doesn't link.
});
```

NOTE: I use jQuery, so you need the jQuery library.
NOTE 2: Add `class="iftablet"` to the links around the boxes, and add as well `tablet_id="X"` (Where X is a unique number for that box, so that when click on one box, the others will disapear).

Maybe there is some errors on the code, put then let me know. Good luck

Comment: Awesome. I will experiment with this for a little bit and get back to you. Thanks for teaching!